# Video cannot close from fullscreen in react-native webview (ios)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, video, react-native-webview

I am using `react-native-community/react-native-webview` and on the website we have `Nexx` player for playing videos.

Android works fine but I have problems with ios. On ios, I have a fullscreen modal where is possible to play video. And if I click on play button video jump into fullscreen mode and start playing. That is right. But if I want to close video by `X` button on the corner Video will jump back to start position and immediately jump back to the fullscreen mode and sometimes show an icon over the video. I will try to close it and the situation will be repeating after a few repeating is finally closed.

[image]

I think the problem is in ios fullscreen video player. Because if I want to play video some fancy webview features will handle video and show it in fullscreen (because Nexx player looks different then this view and I also tried to turn off fullscreen mode but video always jumps in fullscreen). I try to pause the video when it will jump out of fullscreen but it doesn't work. (It works when I pause the video first in fullscreen mode and then I will click on close button = video is close right but if I click on a close button it is doesn't work)

Is there some way how to fix this issues? Or How to control webview feature pause it and then close it when the user clicks on `X` button?

Comment: I am facing the same issue in android

Comment: I have a workaround ... because I have access to all actions in the video and when the user close it I will kill the player and init it again ... it works in my case ...